# How to use len() on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python

When i'm using len() on the terminal it works but when ı use
it on Visual Studio code it doesn't appear.

```
cars = ['bmw', 'audi', 'toyota', 'subaru']
len(cars)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't appear". If you've meant python terminal, then in the VS Code you need `print(len(cars))`.

Comment: yes, that's totaly works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to print it out for it to show

```
cars = ['bmw', 'audi', 'toyota', 'subaru']
print(len(cars))
```

output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Need an interactive enviroment.

Right-click in the code editor and select **Run current file in interactive Window**.

Install the necessary package, then you can get the code result instantly as in the terminal.

Comment: What do you mean "necessary package"?